# How to setup custom Spark parameter in HDInsights cluster with Data Factory

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-hdinsight, azure-data-factory

I am creating HDInsights cluster on Azure according to this [desciption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-create-linux-clusters-adf)

Now I would like to set up spark custom parameter, for example 
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK3_PYTHON or spark_daemon_memory in time of cluster provisioning.

Is it possible to setup using Data Factory/Automation Account? I can not find any example doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SparkConfig` in Data Factory to pass these configurations to Spark.

For example:

```
"typeProperties": {
...
  "sparkConfig": {
     "spark.submit.pyFiles": "/dist/package_name-1.0.0-py3.5.egg",
     "spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/usr/bin/anaconda/envs/py35/bin/python3"
  }
}
```

This way you can specify all Spark configs that are listed in [docs here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#available-properties).