# Execute a PySpark Job with Dependencies using Azure Data Factory V2

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-data-factory

I'd like to execute a PySpark Job with dependencies (either egg or zip files) using Data Factory V2.

When running the command directly on the Head Node cluster (HD Insight) in the form of a spark-submit method it goes as following (and works):

spark-submit --py-files 0.3-py3.6.egg main.py 1

In Data Factory (V2) I tried to define the following:

```
{
    "name": "dimension",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [{
                "name": "Spark1",
                "type": "HDInsightSpark",
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false
                },
                "typeProperties": {
                    "rootPath": "adfspark",
                    "entryFilePath": "main.py",
                    "getDebugInfo": "Always",
                    "sparkConfig": {
                        "spark.submit.pyFiles": "0.3-py3.6.egg"
                    },
                    "sparkJobLinkedService": {
                        "referenceName": "AzureStorageLinkedService",
                        "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                    }
                },
                "linkedServiceName": {
                    "referenceName": "hdinsightlinkedService",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

- Tried to specified the exact path of the dependencies ("wasb://.../0.3-py3.6.egg" or adfspark/pyFiles/0.3-py3.6.egg) like suggested in this thread:
  [How to setup custom Spark parameter in HDInsights cluster with Data Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46814186/how-to-setup-custom-spark-parameter-in-hdinsights-cluster-with-data-factory)

All this in the context that "adfspark" is the container and the dependencies are located in "pyFiles" folder much like it is suggested in Azure documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-transform-data-spark-powershell

Running the job just on the Head Node would be a sufficient start although distributed execution is the real target here